# Kenmore portable washer 665.17779K600

Tags: dishwasher

Anyone knows the internal diameters for the drain and fill hose assembly (unicouple hose) of this model? The part number for the part is WPW10273574. I want to lengthen the hoses by about 2 feet and do not want to dismantle the case to get to the other end of the hoses. I just want to cut and splice two 2 foot lengths of hoses with couplers and clamps.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You'll need to talk to the manufacturer for that info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Somebody must have done what I want to do. Please share. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, but that doesn't mean that this is on-topic for this site. Sorry.